# ftp_put not transferring files to ftp

Tags: php, ftp

I have the following code below, I cannot get why it's not working.

```
    $server=("ftp.blah.com");
    $connect=ftp_connect($server);
    $dest='/';
    $login_result=ftp_login($connect,"blah@blah.com","lol");
    if(!($login_result)||!($connect))
    {
        $error;
    } else {
        echo "success";
    }
    $file= 'Tiny-' . $time. '.txt';
    $upload=ftp_put($connect,$dest,$file,FTP_ASCII);
    if (!$upload)
    {
        echo "failed to upload";
    } else{
        echo "successfully uploaded";
    }
    ftp_close($connect);
```

When i run the code, i get the error "Warning: ftp_put(Tiny-201201070758.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have made the destination folder of the ftp write and read accessible.
I have also tried to include the full path of the text file by:

```
$file= 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Tiny-' . $time. '.txt'
```

or

```
$file= 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Tiny-' . $time. '.txt'
```

I also tried using FTP_Binary instead of ASCII, still no luck.

nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `url_fopen` active on your server? Check with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is active.

Comment: Try to check, if the file you want to put is really there with `file_exists()`

Comment: in local it is, but in ftp its not im refreshing as I run the script and I see nothing

Comment: Maybe use forward slash (/) in filename's path